# Unchecked generics warning in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala, casting, unchecked, unchecked-conversion

I've written a NaturalComparator class/object in Java and rewritten it into Scala:
https://gist.github.com/319827#file_natural_comparator.scala

However, I wonder why I don't need to @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in the Scala version. (I compile it by `fsc -deprecation -unchecked NaturalComparator.scala`.)

- Is Scala powerful enough to recognize that the conversion is OK?
- Does Scala compiles assume that I know what I'm doing when I'm using generics in `.asInftanceOf[...]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala assumes that you know what you're doing.  In this case you *do* know what you're doing, because even though `Comparator` is not marked as contravariant, it acts as though it is (i.e. if you can compare `Any` with `Any`, surely you can compare `T` with `T` for some particular `T`).

If you didn't know what you were doing, it would break with a runtime error.

Generally, one would use pattern matching in cases similar to this:

```
def cast[T](x: Any) = x match {
  case t: T => t
  case _ => throw new Exception
}
```

and now you definitely do get an unchecked warning: because `T` is erased, the match doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I'd expect an compile time error in such case (like with <code>x instanceof T</code> in Java).